# go get command stuck on Mac

Tags: go

I'm trying to install some libraries in golang. But it always stuck when I run go get [package]. The error varies. One of them is like this:

```
➜  alif git:(master) ✗ go get "github.com/go-playground/validator/v10"
go: downloading github.com/go-playground/validator/v10 v10.11.2
go: downloading github.com/go-playground/validator v9.31.0+incompatible
go: github.com/go-playground/validator/v10@v10.11.2: read "https:/proxy.golang.org/@v/v10.11.2.zip": read tcp 192.164.0.2:58505->34.101.4.81:443: read: connection reset by peer
```

Sometimes it is a connection refused or timeout.

```
➜  alif git:(master) ✗ go get "github.com/go-playground/validator/v10"
go: downloading github.com/go-playground/validator/v10 v10.11.2
go: downloading github.com/go-playground/validator v9.31.0+incompatible
go: golang.org/x/crypto@v0.5.0: verifying go.mod: golang.org/x/crypto@v0.5.0/go.mod: Get "https://sum.golang.org/lookup/golang.org/x/crypto@v0.5.0": net/http: TLS handshake timeout
```

My internet work just fine. And in fact previously like 2 days ago, I have no problem downloading go dependencies.

My go version is go1.19, I tried to upgrade it to go1.20 but the problem still occurs. And I'm using macOS M1. What can I do?

Comment: it is a net problem..  just open golang.org/proxy.golang.org in browser,if can't open it, use go_proxy

Comment: @Para it works. Thank you. Maybe you want to create an answer for that so I can accept it or otherwise I'll do it myself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on @Para's comment. I need to use go_proxy.

```
export GOPROXY=https://proxy.golang.org
```

But first, make sure you can open [golang.org/proxy.golang.org](https://golang.org/proxy.golang.org) in your browser or not.

Make sure your `GOPROXY` is set by checking the go env with this command

```
go env
```